# How to remove last item in vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following which add 1 editBox and 1 comboBox every time I click on a button in a userForm :

```
Sub addCable()

    'TextBox creation
    Dim editTxtBox As MSForms.Control
    Static iTxtBox As Integer
    Set editTxtBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    iTxtBox = iTxtBox + 1
    cbxs.Add editTxtBox
    ', editTxtBox.Name
    With editTxtBox
        .Name = "txtBox" & iTxtBox
        .Top = iTxtBox * editTxtBox.Height + 10
        .Left = 20
    End With

    'ComboBox creation
    Dim editCmpBox As MSForms.Control
    Static iCmpBox As Integer
    Set editCmpBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    iCmpBox = iCmpBox + 1
    cbxs.Add editCmpBox
    ', editCmpBox.Name
    With editCmpBox
        .Name = "cmBox" & iCmpBox
        .Top = iCmpBox * editCmpBox.Height + 10
        .Left = 130
        .List = Array("60", "125", "45")
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to implement the undo function, as it delete the last exitBox and the last comboBox created when I click on a button. 
I was thinking to loop over my cbxs collection and remove at the index iTxtBox as iTxtBox is a global variable :

```
Dim num As Integer
MsgBox (iTxtBox)
    For num = iTxtBox To cbxs.Count
        cbxs.Remove iTxtBox
    Next
```

But it doesn't work, I guess it is because my loop is out of the scope I'm looking for....

Comment: Presumably the last added will have the highest number so use that. Or .count to give the required number.

Comment: @QHarr I tried something like : For num = 1 To clcTxt.Count
        clcTxt.Remove clcTxt.Count
    Next
But  i remove all object of my collection, I thought Remove delete the object at the given index.

Comment: @QHarr Also I feel the command Remove is not the appropriate command to delete an editBox from a UserForm because it only removes it from my collection

Comment: You're modifying a collection while you're looping over it. Loop backward and remove the last element until you get to the index you want to stop at.